# Gunicorn + Selenium. Backend chrome are becoming more and more

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, flask, gunicorn

I built a flask service using Gunicorn. But the chrome driver started by service seems not closed. My browser is as follow:

```py
class Browser:
    def __init__(self, path: str, header: bool = False):
        self.path = path
        self.header = header

        self.core_driver = self.init_browser(path, header)
        atexit.register(self.close_browser)
        logger.info(f'browser #{os.getpid()} initialize')

    def close_browser(self) -> None:
        self.core_driver.quit()
```

My packages version:

```
flask==2.0.2  
flask_cors==3.0.10  
gunicorn==20.1.0  
selenium==3.141.0
```

My docker env: `centos/python-38-centos7:20210726-fad62e9`

I tried `atexit.register` and `self.__del__` but not work. Also, I found that if all worker in gunicorn use the same chromedriver this error happens more frequently. While downloading different chromedriver in each process, this phenomenon will appear delayed.